# Why is this writing part of the text to a new line? (Python)

Tags: python, io

I'm adding some new bits to one of the lines in a text file and then writing it along with the rest of the lines in the file to a new file. Referring to the 2nd if statement in the while loop, I want that to be all on the same line:

```
path = raw_input("Enter the name of the destination folder: ")

source_file = open("parameters")
lnum=1
for line in source_file:
    nums = line.split()
    if (lnum==10):
        mTot = float(nums[0])
    if (lnum==11):
        qinit = float(nums[0])
    if (lnum==12):
        qfinal = float(nums[0])
    if (lnum==13):
        qgrowth = float(nums[0])
    if (lnum==14):
        K = float(nums[0])
    lnum = lnum+1

q = qinit
m1 = mTot/(1+qinit)
m2 = (mTot*qinit)/(1+qinit)
taua = (1/3.7)*(mTot**(-4.0/3.0))
taue = taua/K
i = 1
infname = 'parameters'
while (q <= qfinal):
    outfname = path+'/'+str(i)
    oldfile = open(infname)
    lnum=1
    for line in oldfile:
        if (lnum==17):
            line = "{0:.2e}".format(m1)+' '+line
        if (lnum==18):
            line = "{0:.2e}".format(m2)+' '+line+' '+"{0:.2e}".format(taua)+' '+"      {0:.2e}".format(taue)
        newfile = open(outfname,'a')
        newfile.write(line)
        lnum=lnum+1
    oldfile.close()
    newfile.close()
    i=i+1
    q = q + q*(qgrowth)
    m1 = mTot/(1+q)
    m2 = (mTot*q)/(1+q)
```

but taua and taue are being written on the line below the rest of it.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Please post the *actual* code that is free of trivial syntax errors. That is not valid Python code; update the post with the necessary corrections. (This also decreases the chance that the posted code and the actual code are different in other important ways ..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because line still contains the trailing newline, and when you concatenate it you are also including the newline.

Insert a

```
line = line.strip()
```

right after the  `if (lnum == 19):` *but before* you put the longer `line` together to get rid of the newline.

Note that `write` will not add a newline automatically, so you'll want to add a trailing newline of your own.

**UPDATE**:

This is untested, but I think unless I messed up, you could just use this instead of your longer line:

```
 line = line.strip()
 line = "{0:.2e} {} {0:.2e}   {0:.2e}\n".format(x, line, y, z)
```

Comment: And add a (new) newline at the end, no?

Comment: @DSM Yes, since write will not append one .. good point, thanks, I'll update the answer to mention this.

Comment: @Levon fantastic!  It works, thank you.  It's always the little things that get me.

Comment: @whatsherface Happy to help - plase the the update for a more concise approach to format your line

Comment: @DSM You really help keep me "honest" .. your help is much appreciated

Comment: @Levon: hey, I'm happy for someone else to do the real work. :^)

Answer (score 0):

If you use line = rstrip(line) on line before you change the line then it will trim the new line (as well as any whitespace).

Comment: In Python, it's `line = line.rstrip()`.